# How to test Spring PreAuthorize with oauth2 scopes

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, integration-testing

We have an application which is secured with a `ResourceServer` and we are using `GlobalMethodSecurity` to restrict access to API endpoints by client scope. This is all working as expected.

I am now trying to write some integration tests. In my tests I am manually creating a valid JWT and then making calls to the restricted endpoint. If I send no token I get a `401` as expected, but when I send a token that lacks the required scope it is not rejected but is able to hit the endpoint.

I presume that I am missing some configuration or setup to make the `@PreAuthorize` work correctly, but I'm not sure exactly what I am missing.

Here is my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@SpringBootTest
public class UserIT extends BaseIntegrationTest {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext wac;

@Autowired
private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void setup () {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).addFilters(springSecurityFilterChain).build();
}

@Test
public void cannotGetUsersWithoutToken () throws Exception {
    mockMvc
            .perform(get("/user/protected/user"))
            .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
}

@Test
public void cannotGetUsersWithoutCorrectScope () throws Exception {
    String token = getToken(Collections.singletonList("MY_ROLE"), 2);

    mockMvc
            .perform(get("/user/protected/user").header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token))
            .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
    } 
}
```

And here's the API method:

```
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated() and #oauth2.hasScope('my-scope')")
@RequestMapping(value="/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public UserInfo getUser(){
    long userId = getUserId();

    return userService.retrieveUser(userId);
}
```

The first tests passes but the second fails; a `200` is returned instead of `401`.

Any suggestions as to what I'm missing would be appreciated. I have been following this https://www.baeldung.com/oauth-api-testing-with-spring-mvc.